# Unable to load DLL assembly with NET/Link

Tags: .netlink

I am using Math'a 12 on iMac OS 10.14  to load a DLL. To simplify I stored the file in the NoteBook directory, however a listing of assemblies in the directory gives me an error. Ive tried installing and loading the DLL from the three locations suggested in the user guide with the same errors eg *LinkOpen: Could not find MathLink executable*; *InstallNet: A link to the net runtime could not be established*. I used the simple 2 lines of code.

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
LoadNETAssembly[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing incorrectly or suggest a diagnostic test? I checked permissions but they seemed OK.

Edit: Ive found that none of the .NET functions work even from the Tutorial - is there something missing from the installation? Problem also exists on 2012 vintage Mac

Comment: `NETLink` is only supported on Windows. Mac OS cannot load a Windows DLL.

Comment: At last! Why is there no mention in the documentation, or if there is its well hidden. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I do not think this is true ... It may require more setup, but .NET/Link can work on macOS. I believe UnityLink is also based on .NET/Link, and it definitely works on macOS. These are not exactly "Windows DLLs", they are specific to .NET and are in principle platform independent.

Comment: @Szabolcs Interesting, I did not know [this](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.0/3.0-supported-os.md). It has been many years since I worked on .NET/Windows.